# analyze the train-validation accuracy learning curve

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, softmax, cross-entropy

I am building a two-layer neural network from scratch on the Fashion MNIST dataset. In between, using the RELU as activation and on the last layer, I am using softmax cross entropy. I am getting the below learning curve between train and validation accuracy which is wrong obviously. But if you see my loss curve, it's decreasing but my model is not learning. I am not able to my head around where I am going wrong. Could anyone explain these two graphs, like where I could be possibly going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are doing, and I don't know anything about your architecture, but it's wrong to use ReLU on the last layer.

Usually you leave the last layer as **linear** (no activation). This will produce the **logits** that enter the **Softmax**. The output of the softmax will try to approximate the probability distribution on the classes.

This could be a reason for your results.

Comment: I am not using RELU on the last layer. I am using softmax only on the last layer.

Comment: @ffl Sorry I misread your question. Could you provide a schematic or code for your architecture?